# Find the whole path knowing the beginning and the end C#

Tags: c#

I have a path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server", "SqlPackage.exe". 
There are several more folders between the path and the exe file. I would like to check if this exe is in these folders and download the entire path to it.

Do any of these Method provide this option:

- File.Exists
- Path.GetFullPath
- Directory.GetFiles
- Path.GetDirectoryName

How to define this path I tried with "*" but it doesn't work?

Edit:

Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server", "SqlPackage.exe", SearchOption.AllDirectories)

Comment: How about `Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server", "SqlPackage.exe", SearchOption.AllDirectories)` ?

Comment: Check the [Directory.GetFiles function overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_Directory_GetFiles_System_String_System_String_System_IO_SearchOption_) and its code samples